# Laravel - Campo calculado en el modelo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6, laravel-7

estoy con laravel y tengo un modelo **Forms** que tiene una relación 1 a N con **Answers**, y lo que intento hacer es poner en el modelo dicha relación 1 a N, para luego obtener un contador.

**Modelo form**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UsesUuid;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Form extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, UsesUuid;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name','company_id','enabled','uuid','state'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];

 
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FormUser::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FormAnswer::class);
    }
}
```

La relación "answers", es correcta.

Ahora lo que intento obtener es una collections de "forms" y me gustaria incluir en ella una propiedad que fuese el número de elementos preguntas (answers) para dicho form.

Para ello tengo este método

```
    public function formsAccessByUser($user_id) : JsonResponse
{

    $user = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();

    $forms = Form::where('company_id',$user->company_id)->get();

    if ($forms === null) {
        return response()->json('This user has not forms yet', 400);
    }
    
    $numero_respuestas = $forms->answers()->count();
    
    return response()->json($forms, 200);
}
```

Este trozo de código me da error

```
        $numero_respuestas = $forms->answers()->count();
```

El error que recibo es este

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::answers does not exist.
```

De todas formas esta solución no parece muy buena, porque con esto obtendría el valor...pero no lo tendría en la collection.

Alguna forma de hacer esto?

Gracias

Comment: Por qué no utilizas withCount('answers') en vez de hacerlo así?

Comment: Gracias @L.Flor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar withCount que devolverá el total de items seleccionados.

```
Form::where('company_id',$user->company_id)->withCount('answers')->get();
```

Más información https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models